# In Family Guy, what does Quagmire's rodent mean?

Tags: family-guy

In Family Guy, I saw around 2 or 3 episodes showing us a rodent falling off Quagmire's. What does it represent?

Comment: I can't post a full answer just yet, but it relates to Richard Gere and a gerbil, which was a rumour some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

As @Longshanks commented, it is a joke at the expense of the story about Richard Gere stuffing a Gerbil up his rectum [(which Snopes tags as fake)](http://www.snopes.com/risque/homosexuality/gerbil.asp).

In Family Guy, the gerbil is called [Tony](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Tony_(Call_Girl)) and it's just another way to show Quagmire's extreme promiscuity and sexual deviancy.